# Breeze.js Entity Framework multiple one to one of the same type (Parent -> Child childOne, Child childTwo)

Tags: javascript, breeze

I am sure I am doing something wrong but I cannot figure it out. I am using the Breezejs Todo + Knockout example to reproduce my problem. I have the following data model:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
namespace Todo.Models
{
  public class Parent
  {
    public Parent()
    {
    }
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string OtherProperty { get; set; }

    public Child ChildOne { get; set; }

    public Child ChildTwo { get; set; }

  }
  public class Child
  {
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int ParentId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ParentId")]
    public Parent Parent { get; set; }
  }
}
```

In the app I do the following:

```
breeze.NamingConvention.camelCase.setAsDefault();
var manager = new breeze.EntityManager(serviceName);
manager.fetchMetadata().then(function () {
  var parentType = manager.metadataStore.getEntityType('Parent');
  ko.utils.arrayForEach(parentType.getPropertyNames(), function (property) {
    console.log('Parent property ' + property);
  });
  var parent = manager.createEntity('Parent');
  console.log('childOne ' + parent.childOne);
  console.log('childTwo ' + parent.childTwo);
});
```

The issue is that childOne and childTwo are not defined as properties of Parent. **Is there something wrong with my data model?** The log messages are:

```
Parent property id
Parent property otherProperty
childOne undefined
childTwo undefined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Brock, 
you can't have multiple one-to-one associations of the same type.

EF does not support such scenario and the reason is that in a one-to-one relationship EF requires that the primary key of the dependent also be the foreign key. In addition, there is no way for EF to "know" the other end of the association in the Child entity (i.e. what is the InverseProperty of the Parent navigation in the Child entity? - ChildOne or ChildTwo?)

In a one-to-one association you must also define the principal/dependent:

```
  modelBuilder.Entity<Parent>()
      .HasRequired(t => t.ChildOne)
      .WithRequiredPrincipal(t => t.Parent);
```

You might want to check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/jj591620 for details on configuring relationships.

Instead of 2 one-to-one relations, you might want to have a one-to-many association and, handle it in code, so it only has 2 child elements. You might also want an additional property in the Child entity to determine if the child is a "ChildOne" or "ChildTwo".

Comment: OK that is what I figured but I just wanted to be sure since it's a pain to work around.